# Angularjs : directive recursive in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, angularjs-directive

i have a problem with my directive recursive to build a select input.

i have some modules which have some functions and this functions can have some children functions like this :

```
[
  0: {
    module_name : administration
    fonctions : [
       {
         fonction_id : 1
         fonction_name : getAdministration
         children : [
            {
              fonction_id : 2
              fonction_name : getParameters
              children : []
            },
            {
              fonction_id : 3
              fonction_name : getModules
              children : []
            },
            ...
         ]
       },
    ]
  },
  1: {
    module_name : Account
    fonctions : [
       {
         fonction_id : 4
         fonction_name : CreateAccount
         children : []
       },
       {
         fonction_id : 5
         fonction_name : EditAccount
         children : []
       },
       ....
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

the goal is to build *optgroup* in a *select* for each module and put in the *option* each functions of this module and if the function have children, continue on the same *optgroup* else create a new *optgroup* to get this result :

```
<select>
  <optgroup label='Administration'>
    <option value='1'>getAdministration</option>
    <option value='2'>getParameters</option>
    <option value='3'>getModules</option>
    ...
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label='Account'>
    <option value='1'>CreateAccount</option>
    <option value='2'>EditAccount</option>
    ...
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

to make these directives, I was inspired by this article : http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/

see my two directives :

WcSelectOptionGroup :

```
angular.module('app.administration').directive('wcSelectOptionGroup', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            elts: '=',
            selectId: '='
        },
        template: '<select><optgroup' +
                        'label="{{ elt.module_name }}"' +
                        'ng-repeat="elt in elts">' +
                            '<wc-select-option' +
                                'ng-repeat="fnct in elt.fonctions"' +
                                'ng-selected="fnct.fonction_id === selectId"' +
                                'item="fnct"' +
                                'selectId="selectId">' +
                            '</wc-select-option>' +
                  '</optgroup></select>',
        link: function(scope)
        {
            console.log('hello 1!!!!!!!');
        }
    };
});
```

and the second :

WcSelectOption :

```
angular.module('app.administration').directive('wcSelectOption', function($compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            item: '=',
            selectId: '='
        },
        template: '<option' +
                        'value="{{ item.fonction_id }}"' +
                        'ng-selected="item.fonction_id === selectId">' +
                        '{{ item.fonction_title }}' +
                   '</option>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            console.log('hello 2!!!!!!!');
            angular.forEach(scope.item.children, function(child)
            {
                $compile('<wc-select-option' +
                            'item="child"' +
                            'selectId="selectId">' +
                            '</wc-select-option>')
                (scope, function(cloned, scope)
                {
                    element.append(cloned);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and the html :

```
<select
       class="form-control"
       name="parent"
       ng-model="fonction.fonction_parent_id"
       required>
           <option
               value="0"
               ng-selected="fonction.fonction_parent_id === null">
                 Aucun
           </option>
           <optgroup label="{{ $root.getWord('Functions not assigned') }}">
               <option
                   ng-repeat="fnct in fonctions.not_assigned"
                   value="{{ fnct.fonction_id }}"
                   ng-selected="fnct.fonction_id===fonction.fonction_parent_id">
                     {{ fnct.fonction_name }}
               </option>
           </optgroup>
           <wc-select-option-group
               elts="modules"
               selectId="fonction.fonction_parent_id">
           </wc-select-option-group>
</select>
```

When i run the app, the directive WcSelectOptionGroup don't excute because when i put a console.log('hello 1!!!') nothing is happening...
I don't understand why.

So if you have some ideas :)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

finaly i find a solution :)

i made 3 directives : WcSelect, WcSelectOptionGroup and WcSelectOption

see the directives :

*WcSelect*

```
angular.module('app.administration').directive('wcSelect', ['$compile', function($compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            modules: '=',
            fnctsNotAssigned: '=',
            fnctModel : '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/_common/directives/wc-select.tpl.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.$watch('modules', function(newValue)
            {
                if (angular.isArray(newValue) &&
                    newValue.length > 0)
                {
                    angular.element('.optGrpFunctions').remove();

                    var str = '<wc-select-option-group ng-repeat="module in modules" elt="module" select-id="parentId"></wc-select-option-group>';
                    $compile(str)(scope, function(cloned, scope) { element.append(cloned); });
                }
            });

            scope.$watch('fnctModel', function(newValue)
            {    
                if (newValue.fonction_parent_id !== null)
                {
                    angular.element('.optGrpFunctions').remove();
                    scope.parentId = newValue.fonction_parent_id;

                    if (angular.isArray(scope.modules) &&
                      scope.modules.length > 0)
                    {
                        var str = '<wc-select-option-group ng-repeat="module in modules" elt="module" select-id="parentId"></wc-select-option-group>';
                        $compile(str)(scope, function(cloned, scope) { element.append(cloned); });
                    }
                }
            });

            scope.parentId = null;
        }
    };
}]);
```

the template associed :

```
<select
        class="form-control"
        name="parent"
        ng-model="fnctModel.fonction_parent_id"
        required>
    <option
        value="0"
        ng-selected="fnctModel.fonction_parent_id === null">
            Aucun
    </option>
    <optgroup
        label="{{ $root.getWord('Functions not assigned') }}"
        ng-if="fnctsNotAssigned.length > 0">
        <option
            ng-repeat="fnct in fnctsNotAssigned"
            value="{{ fnct.fonction_id }}"
            ng-selected="fnct.fonction_id === fnctModel.fonction_parent_id">
            {{ fnct.fonction_name }}
        </option>
    </optgroup>

</select>
```

*WcSelectOptionGroup*

```
angular.module('app.administration').directive('wcSelectOptionGroup', ['$compile', function($compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            elt: '=',
            selectId: '='
        },
        template: '<optgroup class="optGrpFunctions" label="{{ elt.module_name }}"></optgroup>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            /**
             * ajoute les fonctions de elt a l'optGroup
             *
             * @author tibo
             */
            scope.$watch('elt.fonctions', function(newValue)
            {
                if (angular.isArray(newValue) &&
                   newValue.length > 0)
                {
                    var str = '<wc-select-option ng-repeat="fnct in elt.fonctions" item="fnct" select-id="selectId"></wc-select-option>';
                    $compile(str)(scope, function(cloned, scope) { element.append(cloned); });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and *WcSelectOption*

```
angular.module('app.administration').directive('wcSelectOption', ['$compile', function($compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            item: '=',
            selectId: '='
        },
        template: '<option value="{{ item.fonction_id }}" ng-selected="item.fonction_id === selectId">{{ item.fonction_title }}</option>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            /**
             * ajoute les fonctions enfants de item a loptgroup
             *
             * @author tibo
             */
            scope.$watch('item.children', function(newValue)
            {
                if (angular.isArray(newValue))
                {
                    var str = '<wc-select-option ng-repeat="child in item.children" item="child" select-id="selectId"></wc-select-option>';
                    $compile(str)(scope, function(cloned, scope){ element.after(cloned); });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

i think that my mistake was to put the directive directly in the template of the directive instead of use $compile to execute the directive WcSelectOptionGroup.

bye :)